# Shell script - How do I insert data into a separate file at a specific line?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

In the following shell script, how do I insert `${today}` into a separate existing file index.html at line 4? (Line 1-3 in index.html already has some code. Line 4 is empty. Line 5-EOL has some html code.)

```
#!/bin/sh
Today=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")

#insert ${today} into a separate existing file (index.html) in line 4
#<to-do>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'NR==4 {print strftime("%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S", systime())} 1' file
```

You can also pass in a variable if you don't want to generate the date string inside `awk`:

```
Today=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
awk -vtoday=$Today 'NR==4 {print today} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` utility can insert text at specific lines. This might not be the best way to express it; it overwrites anything it finds on line 4.

```
Today=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
sed -i -e "4s/^.*$/$Today/" index.html
```

The `-i` argument tells sed to edit in place--it effectively overwrites the input file.  I think this option makes sed a better choice than awk for your problem. For testing, remove the `-i` argument, and it will write to stdout instead.

If you want this to work *only* if line 4 is a blank line (no whitespace, no characters), use this instead.

```
Today=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
sed -i -e "4s/^$/$Today/" index.html
```

Comment: Or to insert a line before the current line 4, `sed "4i\\ $Today" file`

Comment: Thank you.  The following command works for me "sed -i -e "4s/^.*$/$Today/" ${newDirName}/index2.html"

Comment: On SO we thank people by upvoting their answers, and by accepting the best answer. I'm glad you found mine useful.